# Add two midi file to animation nodes

Tags: animation, node-editor, animation-nodes

i am using animation nodes in blender for piano animation with this tutorial : 
https://docs.animation-nodes.com/tutorials/midi/ 
my piano notes works but I have piano midi file with 2 tracks ... right hand and left hand
now i cant add this two midi file to nodes ... when I copy this nodes one of them is not works !

[image: Text]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the midi track info node, you can check the name.

In my case it's Piano RH.
By changing the index in get list element you can search for Piano LH.

[image]

If you found that, you can plug both into your loop like this:

[image]

In the loop, you just take the maximum of both values to play:

[image]

result:

[image]

Note: be aware that also the channel is changing in my case - maybe this is also true for yours. Sometimes the right hand might also be saved just on another channel - so you have to search for that and adapt that for your case.

Comment: thanks great again man