# Piano notes in animation nodes not effect with Successive notes

Tags: animation, animation-nodes

I have piano visualizer with animation nodes in blender ... notes in works fine but my problem is successive notes is not work correct ... when two notes is successive the second note is not rotate and both notes

as you can see the notes in midi player is two notes but in blender just rotate 1 time

[image: Text]
[image: Text]

Comment: pls provide blend file, so we can check it out. It may have something to do with the speed/frame, if the "pause" is too short, but i don't know because you didn't provide that information

Comment: @Chris is right.. please share to help is debug for you, if we can, on https://blend-exchange.com/. (Not all of us are running AN, so make allowances)

Comment: @Chris sure ... you can download blend file here : filebin.net/ha95xhhscpnvatlr/blend.zip.zip

Comment: can u pls add a clickable link?

Comment: @Chris   sure: http://filebin.net/ha95xhhscpnvatlr/blend.zip.zip

Comment: i still cannot open that - why didn't you use blend-exchange?

Comment: @Chris blend-exchange doesn't allow to upload zip file for me ...  where can i upload that in blend-exchange ? .... I upload this file to another file sharing platform you can download :
1=> https://filebin.net/7xwd2x8dyszc5lss
2=> https://file.io/m3BhgVf4WPFl

Comment: great! thx, the 2nd works. Could you also provide the .mid file so that i can reproduce it? thx

Comment: @Chris   very thanks man ... this midi file is have 2 notes but in blender just rotate object " 1 " is one time :

https://filebin.net/nfb0haz6j8f9a6kt

   the notes is work in object number 1 ... thanks

Comment: i just changed your mid file by a mid file i used some time ago - and it worked. So i can just assume that your midi-file has not the right or not enough information. Here the proof (other midi file, but your blend file): https://youtu.be/WMSol5yQEhc?si=8U7yjxtMCVQg3Lzg

Comment: @Chris very thanks for your help and record video and upload on youtube , great ... but my problem is not mid file not work in blender ... its works but 2 successive notes not work good ... for example see this online mid editor and download mid file .... this mid have 2 notes in F6 line but in my blender nodes not work exactly

https://onlinesequencer.net/3795420

you can download midi file by click on the near icon of the name of track "Acoustic Guitar (Steel)" and   " Enter the edit mod "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can change the attack time e.g. to 0.2. Then you will at least see that the key will be hit 2 times.

So i think you have to play with these values a bit to get what you want.

[image]

Comment: Thats It ... Very thanks man ... I am beginner in animation nodes and confused when see nodes and connections between them :d  ...   I have another unanswered question in blender stackexchange ... thats simple question for you ... can you please answer that ?
 
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/309748/add-two-midi-file-to-animation-nodes

Comment: i answered it - should work